# How to merge duplicate contacts from evolution

Tags: evolution, contacts

Is there a way to merge two contacts in evolution or with another program relying on evolutio-data-server? I found this two options but they are pretty much out of date: [Plugin](http://zzamboni.org/new/brt/2006/07/09/eliminating-duplicate-contacts-in-evolution-howto/index.html), [Perl Script](http://zzamboni.org/new/brt/2006/07/09/eliminating-duplicate-contacts-in-evolution-howto/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this plugin [EvolutionContactMerge](https://www.gagniard.org/gilles/wiki/wakka.php?wiki=EvolutionContactMerge) from 2009, tested for Evolution 2.26 and 2.28. [Here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1041732) somebody said it works.
I did not test it for recent versions, but maybe it's worth trying out.